# relationship between 2 people on family tree

Tags: php, algorithm, tree, traversal

I am working on a little family tree project (php+mysql) for my parents. Since the whole tree is rather wide and does not fit onto any screen by a long shot, I would like to make a "relationship finder" instead, a way to display the relationship between 2 arbitrary, possibly very distantly related, people.

Every ancestor is stored into a database with his/her own personal ID. Each person ($ancestor[$id]) has 0-2 parents (int IDs) and 0-11 children (array with int IDs):

```
int $ancestor[$id]["father"]
int $ancestor[$id]["mother"]
array $ancestor[$id]["children"]
```

I now need to find the shortest connection between $ancestor[$some_id] and $ancestor[$another_id] as a list of IDs between $some_id and $another_id.

Is there an elegant way/algorithm to do this, short of traversing every possible line up (children) and down (ancestors) until I have found 2 (or none) matching IDs? Any pointer you could give me on the topic would be greatly appreciated, since I have never worked with trees/graphs in that manner before.

cheers

Comment: Have you ever used a breadth first search? That is what you want. You want to start with the child and do a breadth first search over all ancestors until the target ancestor is discovered.

Comment: $some_id and $another_id are most likely not directly related, meaning that one is probably not a child or ancestor of the other. But they most likely share an ancestor some generations back, or a child some generations up. I think the first thing would be to discover that common ancestor/child. Would your breadth search still apply in that case?

Comment: The specific name for that type of search is "Lowest Common Ancestor in a Binary Search Tree." It is very easy to find many algorithms and implementations of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: Well, assuming that everyone has 2^n distinct (grand ^ n-1)parents. There's a famous Stack Overflow question somewhere about that.